# Show that sets of real numbers $A, B$ are adjacent iff $\sup A = \inf B$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> If $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfy :
>   $$\begin{cases}\forall\ a \in A,\ \forall\ b \in B,\ a \le b \cr
>   \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
>     such that }\quad  b-a \le \epsilon\end{cases}$$
>   then we say that  $A$ and $B$ are **adjacent**.
>
> Show that $A$ and $B$ are adjacent if and only if : $\sup(A) = \inf(B)$.

My thoughts :

note that :

$$\sup A =: \begin{cases}\forall\ a \in A,\  ,\ a \le \sup A \cr
  \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \text{
    such that }\quad \epsilon-\sup A  <  a\le \epsilon\end{cases}$$

$$\inf B =: \begin{cases}\forall\ b \in B,\  ,\ \inf B \le b \cr
  \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ b \in B,\ \text{
    such that }\quad \inf B \le b  <  \inf B+\epsilon\end{cases}$$

- **To show the first implication :**

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are adjacent and let's show that $\sup(A)$, and $\inf(B)$ exists such that $\sup(A) = \inf(B)$.

- Show first that $\sup(A)$, and $\inf(B)$ exists :

Let $b\in B$, we have $$\forall a\in A,\quad a \le b$$
then b is  upper bound, $A \neq  \emptyset, A  \subseteq   \mathbb{R}$ then $\sup(A)$ exist.

Let $a\in A$, we have $$\forall b\in B,\quad a \le b$$
then a is  Lower bound, $B \neq  \emptyset, B  \subseteq   \mathbb{R}$ then $\inf(B)$ exist.

- Show first that $\sup(A)=\inf(B)$:

we have :$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
    such that }\quad  b-a \le \epsilon$$

or $$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a,b \in A\times B,\ \text{
    such that }$$
$$ \begin{cases}\epsilon-\sup A  <  a\le \epsilon \cr
   \inf B \le b  <  \inf B+\epsilon\end{cases}$$
$$\iff \begin{cases}-\sup A  <  a\le \sup A-\epsilon\cr
   \inf B \le b  <  \inf B+\epsilon\end{cases}$$
$$\iff \inf B-\sup A  < b-a < \sup A+\inf B $$
$$\iff \inf B-\sup A  < \epsilon \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 $$
i'm stuk here

**or we can say :**

since $\forall a,b \in A\times B \quad  a\leq  b $ then $\forall b\in B,\quad  \sup A \leq b$ then

$$\sup A \leq \inf B **(1)** $$

we have :$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
    such that }\quad  b-a \le \epsilon$$
then 
:$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
    such that }\quad  b<a+\epsilon $$
then 
:$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
    such that }\quad  \inf B \le \sup A + \epsilon $$

Then  $$\inf B \le \sup A **(2)**$$

From  (1) and (2) we have $$  \inf B=\sup A $$

- **To show the second implication :**

Assume that  $\sup(A)$, and $\inf(B)$ exists such that $\sup(A) = \inf(B)$ and let's show that $A$ and $B$ are adjacent

- To show : $$\forall\ a \in A,\ \forall\ b \in B,\ a \le b $$

from the defintion of $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ we have:
$$ \forall\ a \in A,\  ,\ a \le \sup A \text{ and } \forall\ b \in B,\  ,\ \inf B \le b$$
or we know that $\sup(A) = \inf(B)$
then $$\forall\ a \in A,\ \forall\ b \in B,\ a \le \sup A =\inf B\le b $$

- To show : $$  \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \exists\ b \in B \text{
      such that }\quad  b-a \le \epsilon $$

from the defintion of $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ we have:
$$ \ \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a \in A,\ \text{ such that }\quad \epsilon-\sup A  <  a\le \epsilon \text{ and } \forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ b \in B,\ \text{ such that }\quad \inf B \le b  <  \inf B+\epsilon$$

**we can also say that :**

$$\forall\ \epsilon > 0,\ \exists\ a,b \in A\times B,\ \text{
    tell que } \begin{cases}\frac{ \epsilon }{2}-\sup A  <  a\le \frac{ \epsilon }{2}\cr
   \inf B \le b  <  \inf B+\frac{ \epsilon }{2}\end{cases}$$
any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Note that it doesn’t actually ask you to show that $A$ and $B$ are adjacent if and only if $\sup(A)=\inf(B)$: it asks you to show that if $A$ and $B$ are adjacent, then $\sup(A)=\inf(B)$. There’s certainly no harm in showing the stronger statement, though!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $\sup A<\inf B$ take $\epsilon<\inf B-\sup A$. To the reverse consider definition of $\sup$ and $\inf$ with the value $\epsilon/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument might be correct, but it is so clumsy that it  takes about two printed pages. You may use freely the definitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$ as well as their standard properties, e.g., if $z<\sup A$ then there is an $a\in A$ with $z<a\leq\sup A$.

Let two nonempty sets $A$, $B\subset{\mathbb R}$ be given.

(I) If $\sup A=\sigma =\inf B$ then $a\leq\sigma\leq b$ for all $a\in A$ and all $b\in B$. Furthermore, for each $\epsilon>0$, there is an $a'\in A$ and a $b'\in B$ with $\sigma-{\epsilon\over2}<a'\leq\sigma\leq b'<\sigma+{\epsilon\over2}$. It follows that $b'-a'<\epsilon$; whence $A$ and $B$ are adjacent.

(II) If $A$ and $B$ are adjacent then $a\leq b$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$. It follows that any $b\in B$ is an upper bound for $A$, whence $\alpha:=\sup A\leq b$ for all $b\in B$. This says that $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $B$ and allows to conclude that $\alpha\leq\beta:=\inf B$. Now let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. There is an $a'\in A$ and a $b'\in B$ with $b'-a'<\epsilon$. It follows that $a'\leq \alpha\leq\beta\leq b'<a'+\epsilon$, and this implies $\beta-\alpha<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we can conclude that in fact $\alpha=\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof starts off correctly by showing existence of $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ starting with assumption that $A, B$ are adjacent. To be frank, after this step you have lost somewhere in $\epsilon$'s. And it is better to point out the reason why you have lost like that.

Real-analysis is not shunting strange symbols like $\forall, \exists, \epsilon, \delta$ rather it is understanding order relations $(< , >)$ in the field of real numbers. Symbols like $\forall, \exists$ belong to "mathematical logic" and are more suitable for questions in that topic. Remember that *ultimately all the proofs in mathematics are deep down an exercise in mathematical logic* but *looking in such manner at all proofs is not going to help at all*.

Also another point about the textbook from which the question is taken. The definition of **adjacency** in question itself is full of these logical symbols and it clearly points out that the textbook is focusing more on symbol shunting than understanding of concepts. BTW its a typical issue with modern analysis texts (the justification being trying to fit more material in less number of pages).

---

I rephrase the question as follows:

> Two non-empty sets $A, B$ of real numbers are said to be **adjacent** if every member of $A$ is less than or equal to (or we can say "does not exceed") any member of $B$ and we can find a member of $A$ and a member of $B$ which are *as close to each other as we want*. Show that sets $A, B$ are adjacent if and only if $\sup A = \inf B$.

Suppose that $A, B$ are adjacent. Then like you have started with your solution we can prove that $\sup A, \inf B$ exist. We need to show that they are equal. Since every member of $A$ is less than or equal to any member of $B$ it follows that all members of $B$ serve as upper bound of $A$. Hence $\sup A$ is less than or equal to every member of $B$. It then follows that $\sup A$ is a lower bound for $B$ and hence $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

In order to show that $\sup A = \inf B$ we can use the use the technique of "proof by contradiction". Suppose on the contrary that $\sup A < \inf B$ and let $k = \inf B - \sup A$ so that $k > 0$. Then for every $a \in A$ and every $b \in B$ we have $a \leq \sup A < \inf B \leq b$. Thus $(b - a) \geq \inf B - \sup A = k > 0$. Hence we can not find a member of $A$ and a member of $B$ which are as close to each other as we want (their distance will always be greater than or equal to the positive number $k$). It follows that $A, B$ are not-adjacent. This contradiction shows that $\sup A = \inf B$.

To prove the other implication, suppose that $\sup A = \inf B$. Then for every $a \in A$ and every $b \in B$ we have $a \leq \sup A = \inf B \leq b$ so that the first condition for adjacency of $A, B$ is satisfied. Next note that by definition of $\sup A$ we can find a number $a \in A$ such that $a$ is as close to $\sup A$ as we want. Similarly we can find a number $b \in B$ which is as close to $\inf B$ as we want. Since $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ are same (say equal to $K$), we can choose numbers $a \in A, b \in B$ which are as close to a specific number $K$ as we want. Thus both the numbers $a, b$ must also be as close to each other as we want (Obviously *if two numbers are close to a third number then they themselves can not be far apart*. For if $|a - K|$ and $|b - K|$ are small then their sum is also small and $$|a - b| = |(a - K) + (K - b)| \leq |a - K| + |K - b|$$ so that $|a - b|$ is also small.) Thus the second condition for adjacency of $A, B$ is also established and therefore $A, B$ are adjacent.

---

**Note**: The above formulation of the question and the corresponding answer avoids the symbol $\epsilon$ altogether but this does not lead to any loss of rigor. The symbol $\epsilon$ just represents a positive real number (and one can chose any other symbol like $a, b, c, d$ in its place) and its most common use in real-analysis is to quantify the distance between two real numbers. Thus the phrase "two numbers can be chosen as close to each other as we want" means that "for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $a, b$ with $|a - b| < \epsilon$". If a student knows this proper meaning of the phrase "as close to as we want" then he may (and in my opinion perhaps should) avoid the use of $\epsilon$'s in solving small problems like these. $\epsilon$'s are not the substitute for "conceptual understanding".

Answer (score 0):

a lower bound of B-A is infB-supA because subtraction is increasing in the first argument and decreasing in the second argument. Moreover choosing sequences {b_n} going to infB and {a_n} going to supA shows this is inf(B-A). But adjacency is just b-a>=0 for all a,b and b-a<=e for some a,b. But this is precisely inf (B-A)=0.